# How to correctly assert MustHaveHappend(object) in fake it easy

Tags: c#, tdd, automapper, fakeiteasy

I am having a test method that asserts if the CreateClient method of the client account repository has been called. Please See the test bellow.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CreateNewBasicClientAccount_NewBasicClient_CreatesNewClientBasicClient()
    {
        // Arrange

        var clientAccountToCreate = new ClientAccount
        {                
            Name = "Name",                
        };

        var clientAccountToCreateDto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClientAccount, ClientAccountDto>(clientAccountToCreate);


        var clientAccountRepository = A.Fake<IClientAccountRepository>();
        var clientAccountManager = new ClientAccountManager(clientAccountRepository);

        // Act

        clientAccountManager.CreateClient(clientAccountToCreate);

        // Assert

        A.CallTo(
            () => clientAccountRepository.CreateClient(A<ClientAccountDto>.That.IsNotNull<ClientAccountDto>()))
            .MustHaveHappened();

        A.CallTo(
            () => clientAccountRepository.CreateClient(A<ClientAccountDto>.Ignored))
            .MustHaveHappened();

        A.CallTo(
            () => clientAccountRepository.CreateClient(clientAccountToCreateDto))
            .MustHaveHappened();
    }
```

The Act portion of my ClientAccountManager class in the test is calling the CreateClient method of the repository

```
public void CreateClient(ClientAccount client)
    {
        var clientDto = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ClientAccount, ClientAccountDto>(client);
        _clientAccountRepository.CreateClient(clientDto);
    }
```

The first two asserts in the test pass, but the more specific 3rd assert fails with result message

> InterfaceNameSpace.IClientAccountRepository.CreateClient(clientDto: DtoNameSpace.ClientAccountDto)
>     Expected to find it at least once but found it #0 times among the calls:

Both the ClientAccount and ClientAccountDto classes have the exact same properties. Input in getting the failed assert to pass would be appreciated as the code is wired up for it to pass but it fails.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the actual `ClientAccountDto` that is passed to the method is not the same instance as the one you create in your test, so they're not considered equal.

There are several options to solve this:

- override the `Equals` method in `ClientAccountDto` (not ideal, since you normally wouldn't need this for a DTO)
- inject an `IMapper` into `ClientAccountManager`, instead of using the static `Mapper` class, and configure the `IMapper` to return a specific instance of `ClientAccountDto`
- test specific properties of the `ClientAccountDto`, like this:

  ```
  A.CallTo(
      () => clientAccountRepository.CreateClient(A<ClientAccountDto>.That.Matches(x => x.Name == "Name")))
      .MustHaveHappened();
  ```

---

Unrelated note: you don't need to specify the type again in `A<ClientAccountDto>.That.IsNotNull<ClientAccountDto>()`, you can just write `A<ClientAccountDto>.That.IsNotNull()`.